# closure in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
function initialize(final) 
{
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
             ................................................
        }

        var address_array = final.split('~');

        for (var count = 0; count < address_array.length; count++) {
            if (geocoder) {
                geocoder.getLatLng(
        address_array[count],
        makeTheFunction(address_array, count)
    );
            }
        }

  }



  function makeTheFunction(array, thisCount) {
      return function (point) {
          if (!point) {
              alert(array[thisCount] + " not found");
          }


          else {
              var marker = new GMarker(point);
              map.addOverlay(marker);
              GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                  marker.openInfoWindowHtml(array[thisCount] + "</b>");
              });
          }
      };
  }
```

my problem is tht i m not able to access the `array[thisCount]` from the else section although its accessible from the if block.. i.e `alert(array[thisCount] + " not found");` is working
please help

Comment: can you try placing an alert in the else branch - I suspect that should work okay, which means that the problem is what the addListener method is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it inaccessible within **else** block or within “click” handler? If you cannot get array/thisCount only within your “click” handler, have you tried to copy these variables? Can it be an issue with contexts? Try this, if your array is visible within **else** block:

```
function makeTheFunction(array, thisCount) {
  return function (point) {
      if (!point) {
          alert(array[thisCount] + " not found");
      }


      else {
          var item = array[thisCount];
          var marker = new GMarker(point);
          map.addOverlay(marker);
          GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
              marker.openInfoWindowHtml(item + "</b>");
          });
      }
  };
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeTheFunction(array, thisCount) 
{         
          if (!point) 
          {
              alert(array[thisCount] + " not found");
          }
          else 
          {
              var marker = new GMarker(point);
              map.addOverlay(marker);
              GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                  marker.openInfoWindowHtml(array[thisCount] + "</b>");
              });
          }
      return point;
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't do that same thing as the function he gave.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that there is something going wrong in the `addListener` function. In the code provided, `thisCount` in the listener should have a closure to thisCount in the `makeTheFunction` function.

The following emulates the posted code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function init() {
  var count = 'the count';
  partTwo(makeFn(count));

  function makeFn(thisCount) {
    return function() {

      // Shows 'thisCount: the count'
      alert('thisCount: ' + thisCount);
      document.getElementById('btn0').addEventListener('click',
        function(){alert('thisCount: ' + thisCount);}, false);
    }
  }
}

function partTwo(fn) {
  fn();
}

window.onload = function() {
  init();
};

</script>

<!-- Shows 'thisCount: the count' -->   
<button id="btn0">Button 0</button>
```

However it attaches the listener using the browsers `addEventListener`, not the apparently custom `addListener`.